# JQuery. Выборка по шаблону

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть много дивов с вот такими ИД,  возможно ли с jquery как то их выбирать явно не указывая ид дива? (не писать $('#name1')

```
<div id="name1"></div>
<div id="name2"></div>
<div id="name3"></div>
<div id="name4"></div>
<div id="name5"></div>
```

Comment: Повтор вопроса:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/174267/

Comment: да такой-же, можно закрывать, в смысле там все варианты покрыты, в том-числе через `[att*="part"]`

Answer (score 1):

можно в цикле

```
 var $collection=$();
 for (var i=0;i<10;i++) $collection=$collection.add($('name'+i));
```

но лучше просто задать им всем какой-нить класс